# Browsers seems to ignore the hosts file while ping works?

Tags: networking, dns, redirection, hosts, hosts-file

I am trying to make xyz.com always map to google.com (216.58.219.206) on my machine (OS X El Capitan).

Made the following changes to the /etc/hosts file:

```
216.58.219.206  xyz.com
```

I've cleared the cache in the browser, restarted - no avail. Browser still goes to the original xyz.com page. Ping to xyz.com does go to google.

What am I missing?

Comment: FYI - Google doesn't use solely the IP you're using there, you may connect to Google via a different IP.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser is telling the server that it's trying to reach `xyz.com`, not `google.com`.

`HTTP/1.1` and later (almost nothing uses 1.0 any more) require the browser to send the server a `Host:` header telling the server which hostname the browser is trying to connect to, in case there are multiple websites hosted on the same IP address on the server.

`/etc/hosts` and even DNS `CNAME` record trickery doesn't get around this.

You might be able to get around this by using `/etc/hosts` to map `xyz.com` to `127.0.0.1` (your local loopback IP address), and run a lightweight `httpd` process that binds only to `127.0.0.1:80`, and issues HTTP redirects (`302 Found`) pointing the browser at `google.com` instead.

I believe this will allow you to type `xyz.com` into your browser and automatically reach `google.com` instead, but I'm pretty sure your address bar will change to showing `google.com`. Hopefully that's acceptable.